# Convert a cell array of vectors to a 2D matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have a cell of form:

```
A = {[1, 2]; ...
     [3, 4, 5]; ...
     [6, 7]};
```

And I want to put cellular elements in a matrix to form:

```
B = [1, 2, 0; ...
     3, 4, 5; ...
     6, 7, 0];
```

How can I accomplish this? Either with or without a loop.

Comment: Are the elements of `A` always going to be vectors?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using [`bsxfun`'](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)s masking capability -

```
function out = cell1D_to_mat2D(A)

lens = cellfun('length',A);
out = zeros(max(lens),numel(lens));
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:max(lens)]',lens(:)');
out(mask) = [A{:}];
out = out.';
```

Sample run -

```
>> A={[1,2];[3,4,5];[6,7];[5,9,5,8,7]};
>> cell1D_to_mat2D(A)
ans =
     1     2     0     0     0
     3     4     5     0     0
     6     7     0     0     0
     5     9     5     8     7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can zero-pad all arrays so they become equal in length and then stack them to create a matrix:

```
maxLen = max(cellfun('length', A));
B=cell2mat([cellfun(@(x) [x, zeros(1,maxLen-numel(x))], A,'uni',0)]);
```